# Looping through unknown identifiers (and unknown amount) in JSON with same attributes inside

Tags: json, node.js, for-loop, key-value

I am using node.js to program.

Here is a simplified example of a JSON I will be receiving:

```
{
  "Transaction ID213": {
    "drink": "milk",
    "food": "eggs",
    "mealType": "breakfast"
  },
  "Transaction ID432": {
    "drink": "beer",
    "food": "steak",
    "mealType": "brunch"
  },
  "Transaction ID908": {
    "drink": "water",
    "food": "tacos",
    "mealType": "dinner"
  },
  "Transaction ID776": {
    "drink": "orange juice",
    "food": "waffles",
    "mealType": "breakfast"
  }
}
```

I know all of the attribute keys within each Transaction ID. I however will/do not know the Transaction ID or how many objects (ids) I will be receiving. There is 4 object ids in the sample. There could be as much as 20,000 that are coming in or as little as 1. The amount is unknown.

For each transaction id I will be be posting the value from each key to an api. I am mapping the value to another JSON format. For example:

```
{
  "PROCESS_MEAL_Input": {
    "LIQUID": TransactionID213.drink,
    "SOLID": TransactionID213.food,
    "TYPE": TransactionID213.mealType
  }
}
```

I will not be able to know the TransactionID213, but I do know the keys inside of it.

I am wondering if there is a way to use a for loop or some other looping structure to get the first object (TransactionID213 which is unknown), POST the attributes within it, then move to the next object. Continue this process until there is no more objects in the JSON. Thank you.

Comment: So basically in your case key is - "Transaction <id_num>"  and data is the other data structure i.e key value pair of drink, food and mealType. Am I right ?

Comment: If at all possible, propose a change to the JSON creator that makes the top-level here an array and the key into a field of the (sub)object.

Comment: @zenwraight Yes.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Will you give me an example please?

Comment: "Transaction ID776" appears 2 times in an object structure ... that does not make any sense for an return API result. That should be an array

Comment: @gray: If you have the ability to influence the response, it may be beneficial to have it changed to `[ 
{
"transaction_id": 213,
"drink": "milk",
"food": "eggs",
"mealType": "breakfast"
}, ... ]`

Comment: @Akrion Good catch. That was an error in my sample. Fixed. It won't appear twice in real applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this?

```js
var obj = {
  "Transaction ID213": {
    drink: "milk",
    food: "eggs",
    mealType: "breakfast"
  },
  "Transaction ID432": {
    drink: "beer",
    food: "steak",
    mealType: "brunch"
  },
  "Transaction ID776": {
    drink: "water",
    food: "tacos",
    mealType: "dinner"
  },
  "Transaction ID777": {
    drink: "orange juice",
    food: "waffles",
    mealType: "breakfast"
  }
};

var arr = [];

for (let p in obj) {      
  let newObj = {
    PROCESS_MEAL_Input: {
      LIQUID: obj[p].drink,
      SOLID: obj[p].food,
      TYPE: obj[p].mealType
    }
  };
 //POST here.   http.request(.... Or something
  arr.push(newObj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This may work. Instead of putting it into an array would I be able to do Post requests inside of the for loop?

They may get messy.. But could work?

Comment: @gray sure, instead of build an array of objects, you could send the post before the push, for example. Sending newObj

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this would help:-

```
var jsonObject = 
{
"Transaction ID213":
{
"drink": "milk",
"food": "eggs",
"mealType": "breakfast"
},
"Transaction ID432":
{
"drink": "beer",
"food": "steak",
"mealType": "brunch"
},
"Transaction ID776":
{
"drink": "water",
"food": "tacos",
"mealType": "dinner"
},
"Transaction ID776":
{
"drink": "orange juice",
"food": "waffles",
"mealType": "breakfast"
}
}

var userStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

var ans = JSON.parse(userStr, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value
  }
  return value;
});

console.log(ans);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So this would make all of the values uppercase? They need to keep there casing and some values will be only numbers.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks @gray